# Operator framework ansible install psycopg2-binary

Tags: kubernetes, pip, ansible

How do I install psycopg2-binary in Operator Framework Ansible? I've tried adding a `RUN pip3 install psycopg2-binary` to the Dockerfile but that returns:

```
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 365, in run
    strip_file_prefix=options.strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 789, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 854, in install
    strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1069, in move_wheel_files
    strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2'
```

PS. I couldn't add Operator-Framework tag because I need 130 more points to be able to ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the origin of the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/bef05f974012ea6698fc9292e8c34ebee7e99690/internal/pkg/scaffold/build_dockerfile.go#L51) and that helped me come up with this:

```
COPY requirements.txt ${HOME}/requirements.txt
USER root
RUN pip3 install -r ${HOME}/requirements.txt
USER ${USER_UID}
```